# Highlight selection using Richfaces JQuery

Tags: jquery, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm trying to highlight a selection in rich:dataGrid. It's like when I click on a link in the dataGrid, a modalPanel will open for the user to select a image and when the modalPanel is closed, the new selected image will be refreshed in the dataGrid. For this, I'm rerendering the dataGrid from the modalPanel. This works fine. Now, I want to highlight the user selection. When I use the below rich:jquery, it's getting highlighted but then the modalPanel popup and rerendering happens. So the highlighted row goes to it's original self.

JSF:

```
<rich:dataGrid value="#{startupBean.choiceKeys}" var="mapEntry" columns="#{startupBean.rowSize}" styleClass="rich-table">


                                 <rich:dataGrid id="choiceSub" styleClass="rich-table" value="#{mapEntry.value}" var="ObjBO" columns="2">
                                       <f:facet name="header">
                                          <h:outputText value="Choice:#{mapEntry.key}"></h:outputText>
                                       </f:facet>
                                 <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" styleClass="className">
                                 <rich:panel>
                                     <f:facet name="header">
                                     <a4j:commandLink id="objs"  action="#{startupBean.getCategory}" reRender="materialTree" oncomplete="Richfaces.showModalPanel('selectMaterial',{top:'100px', left:'400px', height:'450px', width:'450px'});" >
                                        <h:outputText value="#{ObjBO.displayName}" binding="#{startupBean.outTxt}"/>
                                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{startupBean.key}" value="#{mapEntry.key}" />
                                        </a4j:commandLink>   
                                     </f:facet>
                                        <h:graphicImage width="50" height="50" id="choice"  alt="jsf-sun" url="#{ObjBO.color_url}" value="#{ObjBO.color_url}"> 
                                        </h:graphicImage>
                                        </rich:panel> 
                                 </h:panelGrid>
                                 </rich:dataGrid>
                                 <rich:jQuery selector="#choiceSub tr" query="click(function(){jQuery(this).addClass('active-row')})"/>
                        </rich:dataGrid>
```

CSS:

```
.active-row {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Is there any other way of doing it? Please do let me know.

PS: I'm using JSF2.0, Richfaces 3.2, Apache Tomcat 7, Java 1.7.

Thanks,
Jane

Comment: It's RichFaces 3.2. I'm having some problem when using 4.X versions.

Answer (score 1):

When you rerender an element, it gets replaced by the new content generated by server. I.e. any additional formatting or changes which have been previously applied dynamically (as jQuery in rich:jQuery does) is lost. See also the problem description in rich:jQuery manual http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_jQuery.html.

Basically, you must apply the row highlighting again, after the ajax returns. Please comment if you need additional instructions for this.